# why the code add 1 to the length?

Tags: jquery

the link: http://www.mind4m.com/stories.php?pageid=10

what's this line meaning?

```
var curChildIndex = $(this).parent().prevAll().length + 1;
```

select all the li label before the current a label the add one? am i right?  but why it adds one?

```
$(this).parent().children('div:nth-child('+curChildIndex+')')
.fadeIn('normal',function() {
                    $(this).addClass('current');
                });
```

i can't understand this well. could i write this part to `children('div:nth-child(curChildIndex)')`

Comment: can you post the related html? and what are you trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It adds one because the `:nth-child` selector is *one based*, not *zero based*.

If you obtained an array of all of the children, the first one would be the *zeroth* element in the array.

However to access that same element via CSS you'd use `:nth-child(1)`.

See http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

An alternative implementation might be (untested):

```
var curChildIndex = $(this).parent().prevAll().length;

$(this).parent().children('div')
    .eq(curChildIndex)
    .fadeIn('normal',function() {
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
```

But this will only work correctly if *all* of the child elements are `<div>` elements.

Comment: got it, thank you.could i write that part to children('div:nth-child(curChildIndex)')

Comment: @zhuanzhou no, since `curChildIndex` is a variable name, not a valid selector.  That's why in the original they insert its _value_ in the middle of the selector using `' + curChildIndex + '`.

Comment: .eq(curChildIndex) this is ok,GREAT!many thanks. but curChildIndex is an variable. why your don't use + in eq. namely .eq('+ curChildIndex +')

Comment: Alnitak，why you don't use  .eq('+ curChildIndex +') ? thank you

Comment: @zhuanzhou because `.eq()` takes a numeric parameter, not a string.

Comment: but :nth-child() can also  takes a numeric parameter. eg: :nth-child(1). i referred form this http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/. why? thank you

Comment: @zhuanzhou yes, it does, but it's being used as _part of a string selector_, so you have to _concatenate_ the number _into_ the string. `.eq()` is just a plain function which takes a number directly.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `curChildIndex` is used in the selector `nth-child`. It's computed by counting all the previous siblings (`prevAll().length`) and then adding 1 to get to the current index. Note that the first child has index 1 when using `nth-child`.

Example: If the current element is the fourth element of the parent node, then `prevAll()` will return an array of length 3. The code then adds 1 to get the correct index 4.